# NMOS as a switch

Tags: transistors, nmos

I'm doing some simulation with nmos transistor, which supposed to act like a switch according to this picture:

[image]

but after doing the simulation, I get these results:

[image]

I don't understand why the output still have some voltage when the Vgate = 0.  Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Show your schematic, including the load attached to the output of the FET.

Comment: There are 3 missing assumptions for the FET characteristics Vt, Ron, Coss in this weird question Good vs Poor?

Answer (score 3):

You've likely created a [sample-and-hold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_and_hold) circuit, presumably because the load of your switch has some capacitance but does not draw current:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzB8rB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

CLOAD can either be an explicit capacitor that you place intentionally, or simply be the parasitic capacitances of M1's channel and/or input capacitance of the following stage's input transistor (if this were cascaded in a signal chain).

When VGATE is high, the transistor conducts and CLOAD tracks the input voltage. When VGATE is low, the transistor does not conduct and the output voltage is held at the same level (until it decays by leakage).

Note that while the transistor is drawn as shown with the source on the left, the transistor is really a symmetric device with a channel and a gate. As long as VGATE is greater than the *lower* of VIN and VOUT, the channel can form an inversion layer and current can flow.

The following ADEXL + Spectre-MMSIM simulation confirms this behavior:

[image]

[image]

My simulation differs from the OP's by using a swing of 1 V, rather than 3 V, to meet the requirements of my VLSI process. The transistor size is one finger of 10u * 120n.

Comment: If the output goes low during your "sample" pulse , why does it stay high and not "Hold"  . when not sampled?  (-1)  Perhaps a Mux cct might be a better model.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Where on the OP's waveform do you actually observe that behavior? The output goes low during sampling because the nFET conducts current out of the capacitor into the source when its channel is inverted. This is perfectly plausible for the most standard integrated planar nFET imaginable. There's no need for a mux here in the model, and I don't think the downvote is justified (or your explanation for it is insufficiently clear/coherent)

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Further, I simulated this exact configuration as I claim (symmetric FET as switch, *not* a mux) on my TSMC process and was able to essentially replicate the OP's waveform (aside from their one-time artifact at t = 0.5). I still do not (grammatically nor semantically) understand "If the output goes low during your "sample" pulse, why does it stay high and not "Hold" . when not sampled?" - during sampling, output tracks input. During hold, output remains high because the input was high at the end of the sampling period. I respectfully ask that you either clarify or remove the -1

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/ycmt9o95  Thanks for defining your assumptions to this weird question.  Interesting case of input twice the frequency of the sampler

Comment: But why does schematic show 1kHz   and  plots show 1 & 2 MHz square wave  (+1 for effort)

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Your simulation inputs are 180deg out of phase from the waveforms presented by the OP. OP's gate edges align with falling edges of the input, while your link has a rising edge at the source when the gate encounters any edge. Schematic is 1/2 MHz; the rise time of 50ns affects how quickly the inputs slew, and not the actual frequency (cadence doesn't report the frequency for some reason)

Comment: Phase ?  the assumption is using a 1MHz to sample a 2MHz? phase toggles every cycle

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Phase still applies - either the 1 MHz edges align to the 2 MHz's rising edges, or the 1 MHz edges align to the 2 MHz's falling edges. I think your 2-MHz clock is 0.25 usec ahead of/behind mine (which tries to replicate the OP's). Also typo in prior comment, "1/2 MHz" should be "1 Mhz and 2 MHz respectively"

Comment: OK I was able to simulate your assumptions  https://tinyurl.com/y8gnultf  but how this compares to the poor question is a mystery

Comment: The question gives the waveforms; I replicate them to verify my circuit, and explain its behavior as a S-H

Comment: IF you say so, but you get wrong results without correct assumptions for Vgs(th) RdsOn , Ciss, Coss, Cload

Comment: The question is about qualitative behavior. Of course the exact voltages and RC time constants are going to be different - I'm not even using a process that can handle the OP's 3 V. The general behavior of the circuit is still reproduced enough to allow the answer to discuss the phenomenon in question.

Answer (score -1):

**Nch Enhancement FETs** require Drain to be pulled up to sink current from V+.

**When Vgs=0 the switch is OFF thus the Drain is high because of pullup R.**

**If Source (Vs=Va?) is raised to Gate voltage, Vg then Vgs=0 = OFF state**

Drains are always inverting logic level compared to Gate (with respect to source)
... just as for BJT's Collectors are always inverting to Base current.

If NPN base current is 0 it is "OFF"  just like Vgs=0 except FET Gates are like capacitors where the gate threshold  is exceeded the DRAIN "begins" to conduct current exponentially to SOURCE until limited by drain resistor or RdsOn.

Beware of Logic diagram rules: show Positive Supplies above Ground = 0V

Many bad examples below and only four correct "logic" ways. Can you spot them?

[image]